# Laravel 5 PDF footers with blade show blank

Tags: php, laravel, pdf, laravel-5, wkhtmltopdf

I use  [`"barryvdh/laravel-snappy": "^0.4.0"`](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-snappy)

for export pdf.

I want to add footer on my pdf file but when I add `footer-html` on my code show me blank pdf file.

```
public function exportPdf($id)
{
     $pdf = PDF::loadView('TestView::pdf', [my_array]);
     $pdf->setOption('footer-html', View('TestView::pdf_footer'));
     $pdf->setOrientation('landscape');
     $pdf->setPaper('a6');
}
```

And when  I comment this code `$pdf->setOption('footer-html', View('TestView::pdf_footer'));`  show me correct export pdf file.

`TestView::pdf_footer` content:

```
<footer class="footer">
     <div class="u-pattern"></div>
     <div class="u-back-green"></div>
</footer>
```

Comment: Can you add the `wkhtmltopdf` version you are using and the `TestView::pdf_footer` content to your question.

Comment: edit my posttttt

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your Footer needs to be a complete HTML file, otherwise wkhtmltopdf will not render it correctly.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
    <footer class="footer">
        <div class="u-pattern"></div>
        <div class="u-back-green"></div>
    </footer>
</body>
</html>
```